# How to edit multiple files at once in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, atom-editor, text-editor

I am wondering if there is a way to edit multiple files from one single file, similar to how when you search and click on a file name, it goes to that file:

```
Searching 100 files for "foo" (regex, case sensitive)

~/example.txt:
    1  
    2: Hello foo
    4  

~/example2.txt:
    1  
    2: Hello world foo.
    3  
    4: Hello world foo.
    5  Hello world.
```

I'm wondering if you can do the same sort of thing but slightly different. In my case I would like to have x number of files all merged into one, yet when I edit a portion of the file, it gets saved to the appropriate file.

So say I have these 3 files:

```
~/example.txt:
    1  
    2: Hello world.
    3  

~/example2.txt:
    1  
    2: Foo bar.
    3

~/example2.txt:
    1  
    2: A b c...
    3
```

I would like to then be able to merge them into one file, something like:

```
Hello world.

---

Foo bar.

---

A b c...
```

And then when I edit one of the files (`bar -> world`):

```
Hello world.

---

Foo world.

---

A b c...
```

And then I open up the original file, I see that change.

```
~/example.txt:
    1  
    2: Hello world.
    3  

~/example2.txt:
    1  
    2: Foo world.
    3

~/example2.txt:
    1  
    2: A b c...
    3
```

The reason for this is I would like to have multiple single-page views of my source files, say grouped by category ("all the view related code in one file", "all the database stuff in one file", etc.), because it makes it easier to view it as a whole, but then I want to at the same time keep it modular so each file is only concerned with one thing. So basically having multiple views of a file (aggregated in different ways), where I can edit the aggregated version and it updates the original version and keeps them in sync.

If Sublime can't do this, would be interested to know if Atom editor or some other editor can.